# Android Facebook share dialog custom story with url and image

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Below you can find my code for sharing custom story using open graph with some custom fields. Image and Url not working - I'm getting error: com.facebook.FacebookException, and nothing more when Url is added, when I set only image I'm getting Toast with "Unidentified error" message:

```
OpenGraphObject spent = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("namespace:spent");
    spent.setProperty("og:type", "namespace:" + categorySlug.replace("-", "_"));
    //Not working -- spent.setProperty("og:url", "http://example.com");
    //Not working -- spent.setUrl("http://example.com");
    //Not working -- spent.setProperty("og:image", "http://example.com/image.png");
    //Not working -- spent.setImageUrls(Arrays.asList("http://example.com/image.png"));
    spent.setProperty("og:title", "Title");
    spent.setProperty("og:description", "Description");
    spent.setProperty("namespace:hours", container.getHours());
    spent.setProperty("namespace:minutes", container.getMinutes());
    spent.setProperty("namespace:seconds", container.getSeconds());
    spent.setType("namespace:mycustomobject");

    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    action.setProperty("mycostomobject", spent);
    action.setType("namespace:spent");

final FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(
                this,
                action,
                "mycustomobject"
).build();

if(FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(context,FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
    uiLifecycleHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
}
```

Image is showing in preview. But when I click publish I'm getting error mentioned above.
However my request with JSON code is working and sharing an image:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("{")
            .append("\"").append("og:type").append("\":\"").append("namespace:").append(categorySlug.replace("-", "_")).append("\",")
            .append("\"").append("og:url").append("\":\"").append("http://example.com").append("\",")
            .append("\"").append("og:title").append("\":\"").append("Title").append("\",")
            .append("\"").append("og:image").append("\":\"").append("http://example.com/icon.png").append("\",")
            .append("\"").append("og:description").append("\":\"").append("Desc").append("\",")
            .append("\"").append("namespace:hours").append("\":\"").append(container.getHours()).append("\",")
            .append("\"").append("namespace:minutes").append("\":\"").append(container.getMinutes()).append("\",")
            .append("\"").append("namespace:seconds").append("\":\"").append(container.getSeconds()).append("\"")
            .append("}");

final Bundle object = new Bundle();
    object.putString(categorySlug.replace("-","_"), sb.toString());
    object.putBoolean("fb:explicitly_shared", true);

    Request request = new Request(
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            "me/namespace:spent",
            object,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    if(response != null && response.getError() != null) Log.d("Facebook Share", "Error message:" + response.getError().getErrorCode() + ", " + response.getError().getErrorMessage());
                    if(response != null && response.getGraphObject() != null){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
request.executeAsync();
```

Notes:
Images are present in server.
I've changed namespaces and domains so there could be an errors in names

Exception when I uncomment addProperty("og:image",""): https://gist.github.com/Averus89/55a86b3618f143926eb2